# Banner circles responsive

Tags: html, css

I am needing the best way to handle five circles where each are clickable to pages, that part is easy, but where the circles are also handled for responsive. Listed here is the codepen of the desktop look I want, but then when it goes down to mobile I want it to be left and right, so top image, be left, next image be right, and back to left, and so on.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GJBOwP

```css
.hero-intro1 {
    margin-top: 120px;
    text-align: center;
}

.hero-intro1 img {
    max-width: 200px;
    margin-left: 80px;
    margin-right: 80px;
}

.hero-intro2 {
    margin-top: -120px;
    text-align: center;
}

.hero-intro2 img {
    max-width: 200px;
    margin-left: 80px;
    margin-right: 80px;
}


@media (max-width: 1200px) {
    .hero-intro1 {
        margin-top: 120px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .hero-intro1 img {
        max-width: 200px;
        margin-left: 80px;
        margin-right: 80px;
    }

    .hero-intro2 {
        margin-top: 0;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .hero-intro2 img {
        max-width: 200px;
        margin-left: 80px;
        margin-right: 80px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
    .hero-intro1 {
        margin-top: 120px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .hero-intro1 img {
        max-width: 200px;
        margin-left: 80px;
        margin-right: 80px;
    }

    .hero-intro2 {
        margin-top: 0;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .hero-intro2 img {
        max-width: 200px;
        margin-left: 80px;
        margin-right: 80px;
    }

    img.imgright {
        /*margin-top: 50px;*/
        margin-left: 0px;
        margin-right: 0px;
        position: absolute;
        right: 10px;
    }
    img.imgleft {
        /*margin-top: 50px;*/
        margin-left: 0px;
        margin-right: 0px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 10px;
    }

    img.imgmiddle {
        position: absolute;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        top: 150px;
    }

    .hero-intro2 ul li {
        margin-top: 250px;
        margin-bottom: 50px;
    }
}


@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .hero-intro1 {
        margin-top: 120px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .hero-intro1 img {
        max-width: 200px;
        margin-left: 80px;
        margin-right: 80px;
    }

    .hero-intro2 {
        margin-top: 0;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .hero-intro2 img {
        max-width: 200px;
        margin-left: 80px;
        margin-right: 80px;
    }

    img.imgright {
        /*margin-top: 50px;*/
        margin-left: 0px;
        margin-right: 0px;
        position: relative;
        right: 10px;
    }
    img.imgleft {
        /*margin-top: 50px;*/
        margin-left: 0px;
        margin-right: 0px;
        position: relative;
        left: 10px;
    }

 /*   img.imgmiddle {
        position: absolute;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        top: 150px;
    }*/

    .hero-intro2 ul li {
        /*margin-top: 250px;*/
        /*margin-bottom: 50px;*/
    }
}
.list-inline>li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero-intro1">
    <ul class="list-inline intro-social-buttons">   
   <li><img src="http://staging.eminetwork.com/relazenships/wp-content/themes/RELAZENSHIPS/img/corporate-cooperation.png"></li>
   <li><img src="http://staging.eminetwork.com/relazenships/wp-content/themes/RELAZENSHIPS/img/corporate-cooperation.png"></li>
   <li><img src="http://staging.eminetwork.com/relazenships/wp-content/themes/RELAZENSHIPS/img/corporate-cooperation.png"></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="hero-intro2">
    <ul class="list-inline intro-social-buttons">
   <li><img src="http://staging.eminetwork.com/relazenships/wp-content/themes/RELAZENSHIPS/img/corporate-cooperation.png"></li>
   <li><img src="http://staging.eminetwork.com/relazenships/wp-content/themes/RELAZENSHIPS/img/corporate-cooperation.png"></li>       
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: All here is the staging site so you can see what I have so far: http://staging.eminetwork.com/relazenships/

Answer (score 0):

I rewritted all your code in much simplier and flexible way using css flex property.

First, remove both hero- containers, no need with pseudoclass :nth-child():

```
<ul class="list-inline intro-social-buttons">   
   <li><img src="http://staging.eminetwork.com/relazenships/wp-content/themes/RELAZENSHIPS/img/corporate-cooperation.png"></li>
   <li><img src="http://staging.eminetwork.com/relazenships/wp-content/themes/RELAZENSHIPS/img/corporate-cooperation.png"></li>
   <li><img src="http://staging.eminetwork.com/relazenships/wp-content/themes/RELAZENSHIPS/img/corporate-cooperation.png"></li>
   <li><img src="http://staging.eminetwork.com/relazenships/wp-content/themes/RELAZENSHIPS/img/corporate-cooperation.png"></li>
   <li><img src="http://staging.eminetwork.com/relazenships/wp-content/themes/RELAZENSHIPS/img/corporate-cooperation.png"></li>       
</ul>
```

Then the css:

```
.list-inline {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.list-inline > li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
.list-inline > li:nth-child(even) {
  /* we use :nth-child in order to avoid ugly use of 2 different containers */
  margin-top: 120px;
}
/* Following is for smartphones only */
@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .list-inline {
    /* here we revert the behaviour of our elements: from line to column */
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .list-inline > li:nth-child(even) {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left: 120px;
  }
}
```

With this pattern you will be able to easily change and adapt the template of your elements.

[Demo here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RPYpLO)

Comment: Here is the staging site so you can see what I have so far: http://staging.eminetwork.com/relazenships/

Comment: I saw your link but you didn't made the changes I suggested... so, maybe try it before, then I could help you.

Comment: I have made the changes. Sorry was out of town.

Comment: It does for desktop, but when you start going down to tablet and mobile, I want it to center, and then reduce the padding between the circles.

Answer (score 0):

I have used `nth-child` selectors inside `max-width = 768px` to float them left and right. Got rid of the excess margins on various screen sizes.

```css
.hero-intro1 {
  margin-top: 120px;
  text-align: center;
}
.hero-intro1 img {
  max-width: 200px;
  margin-left: 80px;
  margin-right: 80px;
}
.hero-intro2 {
  margin-top: -120px;
  text-align: center;
}
.hero-intro2 img {
  max-width: 200px;
  margin-left: 80px;
  margin-right: 80px;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .hero-intro1 {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .hero-intro1 img {
    max-width: 200px;
    margin-left: 80px;
    margin-right: 80px;
  }
  .hero-intro2 {
    margin-top: 0;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .hero-intro2 img {
    max-width: 200px;
    margin-left: 80px;
    margin-right: 80px;
  }
  img.imgright {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    position: relative;
    right: 10px;
  }
  img.imgleft {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    position: relative;
    left: 10px;
  }
  .hero-intro2 ul li {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  .hero-intro1 ul li:nth-child(1) {
    float: left;
  }
  .hero-intro1 ul li:nth-child(2) {
    float: right;
  }
  .hero-intro1 ul li:nth-child(3) {
    float: left;
  }
  .hero-intro2 ul li:nth-child(1) {
    float: right;
  }
  .hero-intro2 ul li:nth-child(2) {
    float: left;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .hero-intro1 {
    margin-top: 120px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .hero-intro1 img {
    max-width: 200px;
    margin-left: 80px;
    margin-right: 80px;
  }
  .hero-intro2 {
    margin-top: 0;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .hero-intro2 img {
    max-width: 200px;
    margin-left: 80px;
    margin-right: 80px;
  }
  img.imgright {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
  }
  img.imgleft {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
  }
  img.imgmiddle {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 150px;
  }
  .hero-intro2 ul li {
    margin-top: 250px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  .hero-intro1 {
    margin-top: 120px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .hero-intro2 ul li {
    margin: 0;
  }
  .hero-intro1 img {
    max-width: 200px;
    margin-left: 80px;
    margin-right: 80px;
  }
  .hero-intro2 {
    margin-top: 0;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .hero-intro2 img {
    max-width: 200px;
    margin-left: 80px;
    margin-right: 80px;
  }
}
.list-inline>li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero-intro1">
  <ul class="list-inline intro-social-buttons">
    <li>
      <img src="http://staging.eminetwork.com/relazenships/wp-content/themes/RELAZENSHIPS/img/corporate-cooperation.png">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://staging.eminetwork.com/relazenships/wp-content/themes/RELAZENSHIPS/img/corporate-cooperation.png">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://staging.eminetwork.com/relazenships/wp-content/themes/RELAZENSHIPS/img/corporate-cooperation.png">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="hero-intro2">
  <ul class="list-inline intro-social-buttons">
    <li>
      <img src="http://staging.eminetwork.com/relazenships/wp-content/themes/RELAZENSHIPS/img/corporate-cooperation.png">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://staging.eminetwork.com/relazenships/wp-content/themes/RELAZENSHIPS/img/corporate-cooperation.png">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't achieve that when having `li` elments in different `ul` lists. You should keep them in one and reference to `li` elements using `:nth-child` pseudo-selector - that way you can position even elements (each second, as you want).

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pJOePE)

HTML:

```
<ul class="list-inline intro-social-buttons">   
   <li class="item"><img src="http://staging.eminetwork.com/relazenships/wp-content/themes/RELAZENSHIPS/img/corporate-cooperation.png"></li>
   <li class="item"><img src="http://staging.eminetwork.com/relazenships/wp-content/themes/RELAZENSHIPS/img/corporate-cooperation.png"></li>
   <li class="item"><img src="http://staging.eminetwork.com/relazenships/wp-content/themes/RELAZENSHIPS/img/corporate-cooperation.png"></li>
   <li class="item"><img src="http://staging.eminetwork.com/relazenships/wp-content/themes/RELAZENSHIPS/img/corporate-cooperation.png"></li>
   <li class="item"><img src="http://staging.eminetwork.com/relazenships/wp-content/themes/RELAZENSHIPS/img/corporate-cooperation.png"></li>       
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.item {
  display: inline-block;
}
.item:nth-child(even) img {
  margin: 0 -25px;
  position: relative;
  top: 120px;
}
/* Following is for smartphones only */
@media (max-width: 1100px) {
  .list-inline {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .list-inline > li:nth-child(even)   {
    margin: -25px 0;
  }

  .item:nth-child(even) img {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    left: 120px;
    top: 0;
  }

}
```

Comment: Good solution, but what is the point when I just posted the same 15 minutes before ?

Comment: Well, I checked your code in my browser (latest chrome) and it did not align left/right for mobile http://take.ms/azqZK